# How to deny choose same file with JFileChooser

Tags: java, swing, jfilechooser, jtabbedpane

I am creating program whose function is that reading "n" .txt or .java files and of these files creates a UML diagram. I have reading method, but I came to problem with load more same files. I would like to deny load same files, because it makes problems with creating a UML diagram.

I trying to solve it so that I store uploaded file into ArrayList and checking each load file with files saved in ArrayList, where are previous loaded files.

Next problem is that I click to button Yes or No when I choose same file, file is equally loaded.

And when I creating this answer I found next problem. When user select more then one file, ArrayList don't know how to add two files at once.

Is there anyone option how I would solve this problem more easily?

```
ArrayList<String> filenames = new ArrayList<String>();
JTabbedPane tabbedPaneUML_Files = new JTabbedPane();

private void readFiles() {
    JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();
    fc.setMultiSelectionEnabled(true);
    FileNameExtensionFilter fileFilter =
            new FileNameExtensionFilter("Only .txt a .java files",
            "txt", "java");
    fc.setFileFilter(fileFilter);
    int returnValue = fc.showOpenDialog(this);        

    if (returnValue == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
        File[] files = fc.getSelectedFiles();
        File file;            
        tabbedPaneUML_Files.addTab("UML diagram", panelUML);

        for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
            file = files[i];

            for (int j = 0; j < filenames.size(); j++) {
                if (filenames.get(i).equals(fc.getSelectedFile().getName())) {
                    Object[] options = {"Yes", "No"};

                    int answer = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(this,
                            "Unable to load the same files! To retrieve the other files?",
                            "Load new file", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION,
                            JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE, null, options, options[0]);     

                    if(answer == 0) {
                        readFiles();
                    }
                }
            }         
            filenames.add(file.getName());
            JTextArea loadCode = new JTextArea();
            JScrollPane scrollingFile = new JScrollPane();
            scrollingFile.setViewportView(loadCode);
            tabbedPaneUML_Files.addTab("" + file.getName(), scrollingFile);
            int ch;

            try {
                Reader charsReader =
                        new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(file),
                        "UTF-8");

                while ((ch = charsReader.read()) != -1) {
                    loadCode.append(Character.toString((char) ch));
                }
                loadCode.setSelectionStart(0);
                loadCode.setSelectionEnd(0);
                loadCode.setEditable(false);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(HlavniOkno.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(HlavniOkno.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks for any advice. I already lost ideas. 
Sorry for my English.

Comment: *"I have reading method, but I came to problem with load more same files."*  You should just 'flip to that tab' (or whatever is appropriate for the GUI) for the already opened file.  Also consider offering the user to open a group of files at once - then they can select all the files for a particular UML diagram.  Of course, failing that, you might look to use a custom [FileSystemView](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/filechooser/FileSystemView.html).

Comment: That's true. My biggest problem is that I do not know how it would be best for users to create this readout method. If you allow selecting multiple files at once (= problems, but user-friendly), if you allow the same file (I think it is good that I do not allow the same file) etc.

Can you have a problem that could occur when creating UML diagram? Or, conversely, what would be nice to add to this method?

Thank you for your ideas.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the validatedFileChooser found [here](http://www.isaacsukin.com/news/2011/11/04/java-validated-filechooser)

and tweak it so instead of having a list of invalid filenames, have a list of the already chosen files.
Then you can just edit this part:

> ```
> if (file.exists() && getDialogType() == SAVE_DIALOG) {
> int confirm = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog( this, file.getName() + " already exists! Would you like to overwrite it?", "File already exists", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION, JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE );
> if (confirm != JOptionPane.YES_OPTION)
> return;
> }
> ```

to say `getDialogType() == LOAD_DIALOG` and the error message to: "file has already been loaded" for example.

As for the multiple filenames, do `File[] files = chooser.getSelectedFiles();` to get the list of files chosen, iterate through them to get their names and then store them in the array for already selected filenames.

*edit* - sorry just saw you have already done `File[] files = chooser.getSelectedFiles();`, so all you need to do is add it to the array containing the already loaded filenames.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I look at that page.

Comment: I read that page (class). It looks interesting. I'll try to tweak, but I think it is too difficult for me. It would be nice if it worked in my imagination. Maybe but I want it too :)

Comment: Sorry, I do not know how to use the class. I understand what is going on (I hope). How I use something like showOpenDialog? Thank you.